Best way use multithreading/multiprocessing for file operations in Electron
I am writing an app that loads various files and folders from the user's filesystem, fetches some data from the files (eg. the file's icon), and then displays the information in the app for each file. It works great except that the app hangs while this information is being gathered and displayed.
I've tried making this asynchronous (via await/async, by using Promises, and through setTimeout), but it does not impact performance much. I have also tried using Javascript's Web Workers, but the Electron docs warn against doing this with built-in NodeJs modules (I am using path and fs), and on top of that, using const { app, } = require('electron'); const blankIcon = app.getFileIcon("/path/to/file.txt") in a worker script doesn't seem to work, even with nodeIntegrationInWorker set to true.
My question is this: in general, what is the best way to use async/threads/multiprocessing to run filesystem operations and display the results in an Electron app without making the app hang?
Apologies if this question is a bit vague. I have not been able to find much helpful information on this elsewhere on the internet.
Thanks in advance!

"warn against doing this with built-in NodeJs modules" - it warns against native modules, which is a different thing. " it does not impact performance" - what did you try and how do you estimate the performance? Does "app hangs" apply?

Good to know about native modules. I tries putting await in front of my call to the function that does all the file operations and puts the info in the app, tried using return new Promise(function(resolve) {function()}) both in the call to the function and in the function, and likewise with setTimeout(() => {function()}, "10");. In all cases the app still hangs.
`

"function that does all the file operations" - this depends on the implementation, consider addressing it. Nothing good happens if you're wrapping blocking code like fs.readFileSync with non-blocking like setTimeout. Make sure you use non-blocking apis like Node fs.promises, etc

The few fs functions I am using aren't in fs.promises. I've done some more digging and it looks like there's no easy way to access the renderer from another thread/process without still causing hanging (i.e. via IPC). Oh well.

Depends on the functions. If they are blocking main thread then that's it. It's possible to move blocking operations to a worker in Node (worker_threads module), but I'm unaware if it works ok in Electron, and you have to interact with a worker any way, could become a bottleneck

Yes, I tried but to send the information back to the renderer and update the page for so many items was still too much of a bottleneck. Thanks again for the ideas though.
